# Bootstrap sidebar nav like on components site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, sidebar

I would like to build a sidebar navigation that behavaves exactly like on the bootsrap components page with the difference that it should appear on the left side:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Requirements:

- Set active class related to last viewed heading
- Collapse/Expand childrens

Is there a predefined way realize this?

Answer (score 7):

http://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/

You can find the exact table of contents Bootstrap is using on that page.

**Usage**

On top of the normal Bootstrap setup (see their Getting Started guide), you will need to include the Bootstrap Table of Contents stylesheet and JavaScript file.

```
<!-- add after bootstrap.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/v0.3.0/dist/bootstrap-toc.min.css">
<!-- add after bootstrap.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/v0.3.0/dist/bootstrap-toc.min.js"></script>
```

**Via data attributes**

*Simplest.*

Create a `<nav>` element with a `data-toggle="toc"` attribute.

```
<nav id="toc" data-toggle="toc"></nav>
```

You can put this wherever on the page you like. Since this plugin leverages Bootstrap’s Scrollspy plugin, you will also need to add a couple attributes to the `<body>`:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#toc">
```

**Via JavaScript**

*If you need customization.*

If you prefer to create your navigation element another way (e.g. within single-page apps), you can pass a jQuery object into `Toc.init().`

```
$(function() {
var navSelector = '<something>';
var $myNav = $(navSelector);
Toc.init($myNav);
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: navSelector
  });
});
```

See the Scrollspy documentation for more information about initializing that plugin.

**Options**

When calling `Toc.init()`, you can either pass in the jQuery object for the `<nav>` element (as seen above), or an options object:

```
Toc.init({
  $nav: $('#myNav'),
  // ...
});
```

All options are optional, unless otherwise indicated.

Comment: Just for your information. The JS example taken from the docs is wrong: https://github.com/afeld/bootstrap-toc/issues/18

Comment: @user3631654 You could update my question with the correct info, I did it now for future reference.